App now crashes on Pixel devices running Android 14 in TimePickerDialog
My app has suddenly started crashing using the TimePickerDialog API.  This is only happening on Google Pixel 6, 7, and 8's running Android 14.  I see there was a security update March 4, 2024 and the crashes started on March 7, 2024 - maybe there's a connection?  No other Android 14 device is affected and other Android versions are fine!
I have a Cordova app that uses the plugin https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker.
Crashes occur when the user invokes the date and time picker, chooses the date (which is fine), but anything the user does with the time picker (hits the + or -, types in hour or minute and taps "next") causes a crash.
I looked in the Google issues tracker and don't see anything relevant: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20timepickerdialog
Here is a snippet of the code the plugin is using (written a few years ago):
 final TimePickerDialog timeDialog = new TimePickerDialog(currentCtx, theme, timeSetListener, jsonDate.hour,
        jsonDate.minutes, jsonDate.is24Hour) {
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            timePicker = view;
            timePickerHour = hourOfDay;
            timePickerMinute = minute;
        }
    };

Here is the crash log
 Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.EditText.hasFocus()' on a null object reference
   at android.widget.TimePickerSpinnerDelegate.updateInputState (TimePickerSpinnerDelegate.java:480)
   at android.widget.TimePickerSpinnerDelegate.-$$Nest$mupdateInputState
   at android.widget.TimePickerSpinnerDelegate$2.onValueChange (TimePickerSpinnerDelegate.java:119)
   at android.widget.NumberPicker.notifyChange (NumberPicker.java:2080)
   at android.widget.NumberPicker.setValueInternal (NumberPicker.java:1850)
   at android.widget.NumberPicker.validateInputTextView (NumberPicker.java:2030)
   at android.widget.NumberPicker.-$$Nest$mvalidateInputTextView
   at android.widget.NumberPicker$3.onFocusChange (NumberPicker.java:769)
   at android.view.View.onFocusChanged (View.java:8411)
   at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged (TextView.java:12813)
   at android.view.View.clearFocusInternal (View.java:8241)
   at android.view.View.clearFocus (View.java:8220)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.clearFocus (ViewGroup.java:1196)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.clearFocus (ViewGroup.java:1196)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.clearFocus (ViewGroup.java:1196)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.clearFocus (ViewGroup.java:1196)
   at android.app.TimePickerDialog$1.onClick (TimePickerDialog.java:159)
   at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:7729)
   at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:7706)
   at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:30484)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:959)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:232)
   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:317)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8501)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:552)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:878)

Any help would be most appreciated!
Thanks,
- Jon

I encountered essentially the same error on Android 14, so I switched to this:
https://www.cssscript.com/mobile-ios-date-picker-rolldate/.
I adapted the code to suit my preferences. Now, I have a more consistent UI between iOS and Android.

You shall start using latest API TimePickerDialog.
Just replace your code to display picker dialog like below:
new TimePickerDialog(context, OnTimeSetListener, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);

If you need to set theme, add theme after the 'context' parameter above.

It's listed now under https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/333670354
My wife Pixel 7A doing this for a few weeks/month
My Pixel 3XL is not having this issue
We are both using the same Lorex Cloud app version that use that timepicker
